# Cannot acess a JSP page using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'd would like to add mapping in `Spring Boot` (1.5.4) for a `jsp` page. First of all, I started by creating in project in `IntelliJ`. Then I added a few packages in `pom.xml`. Now I have in this file the following dependencies:

- spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf
- spring-boot-starter-web
- tomcat-embed-jasper
- spring-boot-devtools
- spring-boot-starter-test
- jstl

Next, I created a class to make a mapping for `/login`.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController
{
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login()
    {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

I created `login.jsp` file in the location of `src/main/webapp/web-inf/jsp`.

[image]

Lastly, I added the following in `application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
```

Unfortunelty, when I try access `localhost/login` I get the `Whitelabel Error Page` page.
What have I missed with configuration?

Comment: What does your log say in IntelliJ console? Maybe adding Thymeleaf as a dependency mixes things up, as it searches for templates in the src/main/resources/templates folder. Try putting your .jsp  there, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: Oh, your WEB-INF folder must be capitalized, web-inf won't work!

Comment: Unfortunetly, neither worked.

Comment: There must be some exceptions in the log which can be a hint for the problem.

Comment: What packaging did you use? Maybe you used jar, but war would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem today and have found your question while googling the solution.

It is a common IntelliJ problem, so, I'll tell you, what I have done to make app work (hope it will help).

First of all, try to go to http://localhost:8080/login (you mentioned localhost without port number). 
If this doesn't help, try the following steps:

1. Change your package name to the same case as in properties-file (WEB-INF instead of lowercase).
2. Go to Project Structure (CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S on Windows/Linux) -> Modules -> find the module with your project name -> expand it -> Web -> Web Resources Directories: "Web Resource Directory" - should be the path to your webapp folder (for example, on my Linux machine it was /home/user/Documents/Java/Projects/myproject/src/main/webapp ), "Path Relative to Deployment Root" - "/" (without quotes)  -> Apply.
3. Return to module with the same name as your project and instead of Web choose Spring -> check that your main class should be mentioned there twice and your properties file once (if no, add them by "+" button).
4. Click on Select Run/Debug Configuration (a block with your main class name near Run button) -> Edit configurations... -> Code Coverage tab -> Packages and classes to record coverage data: Add package (green plus with small package icon button) -> type your classpath + ".*" (without quotes) (for example, com.example.*) -> Is Active and Include/Exclude checkboxes should be checked -> OK.
5. Open IntelliJ Terminal, type "mvn clean install" (without quotes) -> ENTER -> wait untill the process will finish -> you shoul see a message something like:

   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
   [INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Total time: 9.339 s
   [INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-03T00:46:58+02:00
   [INFO] Final Memory: 36M/273M
   [INFO]
6. Go to browser -> http://localhost:8080/login -> your login.jsp page should appear (if no luck try CTRL+F5 on Windows/Linux to refresh webpage cash).

Hope this gonna help you, as it works for me.

Have fun! =)